# MomentJS isAfter doesn't work when including days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to use MomentJS to compare two dates. This is the code I'm using:

```
var returnTime = moment(fetchedReturnTime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
var timeThreeDays = moment().add(3, 'days').utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var beginningTime = moment('8:45am', 'h:mma');
var endTime = moment('9:00am', 'h:mma');
console.log(timeThreeDays.isAfter(returnTime)); // true
```

When I use `isAfter` with `beginningTime` and `endTime`, the comparsion works, but when I use it with `returnTime` and `timeThreeDays` I get the error that `timeThreeDays.isAfter is not a function`. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Because `timeThreeDays` is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll be down to a type mismatch. 
Your `returnTime` and `timeThreeDays` variables will be `string` types, your other variables are `moment` objects. Moment being a wrapper around the `Date` object.

If you want to compare these, remove the `format` method call first.